# Enviar um blob para um webservice

Tags: node.js, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, integração, couchdb

Olá, pode parecer Jr. a pergunta pessoal mas já tentei procurar na internet e nada.

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

Uma API em .NET fornecida por uma empresa a qual eu tenho que enviar um arquivo, e meu BackEnd em NodeJS.

Esse BackEnd em NodeJS se conecta com o CouchDB e recupera um anexo dentro de um documento. Esse anexo me é retornado como um Blob, eu preciso enviar esse Blob para a API em .NET.

Tentei encontrar exemplos na internet, porém toda hora caio em um artigo ensinando a receber um arquivo "no" NodeJS sendo que na realidade eu quero enviar um arquivo pelo NodeJS.

Obrigado.